# IIS prevent image hotlinking both HTTP and HTTPS

Tags: iis, web-config

I am using this code to prevent image hot linking however

```
<rule name="Prevent Hotlinking">
    <match url=".*\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|bmp)$"/>
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_REFERER}" pattern="^$" negate="true" />
        <add input="{HTTP_REFERER}" pattern="^http://domain\.com/.*$" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/img/hotlink-logo.png" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

however when I visit a HTTPS section all my images are replaced with the hotlink-logo.png. I tried adding a second rule to manage hTTPS requests but same issue occurs.

I tried adding a second condition for HTTPS but then hotlinking is allowed again.

Any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include both of your URLs in the regex:

```
^https?://domain\.com/.*$
```

Comment: Isn't the referer header not always provided by the client browser ?

Comment: @Jonathan: Correct.

Comment: @SLaks So this solution could prevent images from displaying even on your own domain